# Error while uploading a file in wordpress "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress 5.3.2 , while uploading any media ,plugin or theme file I am getting error

> "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"

I had check all the permission of parent folder and permission is 755.

Still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

**It must be issue of File Permission Follow The Following Steps.**

1.To give all permissions to a folder give chmod -R 777:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /path/to/directory
```

or 
    sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/directory

or 
Yo Can Also Give Permission Via Filezilla Parent Directory Recursively.

2.In wp-config.php 
Add Code Before require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Hope This Will Be Helpful.
https://wp-me.com/fix-unable-to-create-directory-wp-content-uploads-is-its-parent-directory-writable-by-the-server/

Comment: if Your Issue Will Be Resolved Then Please, Mark My Answer As Correct. Thank You.